# Alternative proof to Folland 6.19 (Minkowski's Inequality for Integrals)?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> **Theorem 6.19.** In short, we want to show
>
> $$\left\|\int |f(\cdot, y)|\,d\nu(y)\right\|_p \leq \int \|f(\cdot, y)\|_p \, d\nu(y)$$
>
> for m'ble $f$.

---

Could we prove this using just the duality of the norm? That is, there exists some $g \in L^q(\mu)$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
\left\|\int |f(\cdot, y)|\,d\nu(y)\right\|_p &= \sup_{\|g\|_q = 1} \iint |f(x,y)||g(x)| \, d\mu(x) \, d\nu(y) \\
&= \sup_{\|g\|_q = 1}\iint |f(x,y)||g(x)| \, d\nu(y) \, d\mu(x) \tag{Fubini} \\
&\leq \int \left(\sup_{\|g\|_q = 1} \int |f(x,y)| |g(x)| \, d\nu(y) \right) \, d\mu(x) \tag{$\dagger$}\\
&= \int \|f(\cdot, y)\|_p \, d\nu(y).
\end{align}
$$

where for $(\dagger)$, I used the fact that for m'ble $h$ we have, $\sup\int h \leq \int \sup h$.

Am I overlooking anything? It seems this is nicer than the approach used in the book.

Comment: This proof is fine.